# Experimenting with converting some jQuery to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

So, I have been trying to, just for knowledge's sake, convert some of my jQuery into plain, vanilla javascript. I'd just like to get some comments on if there is a better way I could have re-written this. (It's also in coffeescript.)

The script itself listens for click events on the element  for example, finds the  with the same ID as the data-modal element and then attaches a class to that element, which makes a window pop up, basically. Then, the overlay class listens for a click event, which removes the previously attached class 'md-show' from any  that has it. It's just a simple script really, that adds and removes a class in order to show a popup window.

Thanks for any and all help.

Here is the original jQuery:

```
    overlay = $('.md-overlay')
$('.md-trigger').click (e) ->
    modal = $(@).data 'modal'
    modalID = '#' + modal
    $(modalID).addClass 'md-show'
    e.preventDefault()
$('.md-close').click ->
    $("div[id^='modal']").removeClass 'md-show'
overlay.click ->
    $("div[id^='modal']").removeClass 'md-show'
```

And here is the conversion to vanilla js:

```
    hasClass = (el, cl) ->
    regex = new RegExp('(?:\\s|^)' + cl + '(?:\\s|$)')
    !!el.className.match(regex)

overlay = document.getElementsByClassName('md-overlay')[0]
triggers = document.getElementsByClassName('md-trigger')
modals  = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='modal']")

for i in [0...triggers.length]
    trigger = triggers[i]
    trigger.addEventListener 'click', (e) ->
        modal = this.getAttribute 'data-modal'
        modalID = document.getElementById(modal)
        modalID.classList.add 'md-show'
        return false

overlay.addEventListener 'click', ->
    for i in [0...modals.length]
        eachModal = modals[i]
        if hasClass(eachModal, 'md-show')
            eachModal.classList.remove 'md-show'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoffeeScript takes care of proper iteration through an array for you. So

```
for i in [0...triggers.length]
    trigger = triggers[i]
    trigger.addEventListener 'click' ...
```

can be written more concisely as:

```
for t in triggers
    t.addEventListener 'click' ...
```